# Is there a class template to help Load/Create/ Save my own custom config file in c#?

Tags: c#

I have created my own config files for my application 2 to be exact. The config data is encrypted and cant be read unless it is decrypted.

Now each config has a different object with properties.

So there are 2 files
A1Config.cfg
A2Config.cfg

The config object for each is A1CFGObject for A1Config.cfg and has properies.
I will just give a few.

```
 UserId
 FirstName
 LastName
 Address
```

A1CFGObject  for A2Config.cfg
Properties:

```
UserId
FirstName
LastName
Address
ClubMembershipNumber
ClientId
AccountNumber
```

At any time both files will need to be updated if a user changes inputs on the screen.
Also when the firstname, lastname , userid and address are the same in both.

At the moment i call UpdateFile(.....) with a number of parameters and update. I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this , like creating a class
that has a number of properties and I can just pass in the parameter the Objects and set the values then save.
So something like

```
 public static class Load()
 public static class Save()
 public static class Create()
```

and just call these methods throughout my app.

Is there a sample class that can do this ?

Comment: From what you have posted, I'd say no. But if you don’t want the Methods to be in program.cs, you could create your own static class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating your own config file, if you use the C# System.Configuration namespace to create custom config sections with your own schema like id, username, address etc. you will be able to avoid implementing CRUD operations by yourself. Using built-in libraries is always better since any code you write you need to maintain, fix bugs etc.

Using the System.Configuration namespace, you can create new config files with custom config sections. Encryption of sensitive values is also provided by the library. Here are some links to get started

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/store-custom-information-config-file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Please reply if you want more elaboration on this approach.